# Interpreting iozone results

Tags: io, ssd, iozone

This is using a **Samsung 960 Pro on Arch linux x64, linux 4.9.8-1, iozone3_465 (latest tar)**

For example, the last line:

```
    kB  reclen    write  rewrite    read    reread    read     write     read   rewrite      read   fwrite frewrite    fread  freread
524288   16384  3076538  4731679  6996177  7957390  9027307  5270393  7794836   5642908   8827171  4345708  3788703  6670158  9066648
```

Does this mean the write speeds are 3Gb/s for a file size of 524M with a record length of 16M?

And if that is the case, why would a file size of 4096 with a record length of 4096 have lower write speeds? (1.5 Gb/s)

**iozone -a** results:

```
[ @ current]$ ./iozone -a
    Iozone: Performance Test of File I/O
            Version $Revision: 3.465 $
        Compiled for 64 bit mode.
        Build: linux-AMD64 

    Contributors:William Norcott, Don Capps, Isom Crawford, Kirby Collins
                 Al Slater, Scott Rhine, Mike Wisner, Ken Goss
                 Steve Landherr, Brad Smith, Mark Kelly, Dr. Alain CYR,
                 Randy Dunlap, Mark Montague, Dan Million, Gavin Brebner,
                 Jean-Marc Zucconi, Jeff Blomberg, Benny Halevy, Dave Boone,
                 Erik Habbinga, Kris Strecker, Walter Wong, Joshua Root,
                 Fabrice Bacchella, Zhenghua Xue, Qin Li, Darren Sawyer,
                 Vangel Bojaxhi, Ben England, Vikentsi Lapa,
                 Alexey Skidanov.

    Run began: Wed Feb 15 23:30:38 2017

    Auto Mode
    Command line used: ./iozone -a
    Output is in kBytes/sec
    Time Resolution = 0.000001 seconds.
    Processor cache size set to 1024 kBytes.
    Processor cache line size set to 32 bytes.
    File stride size set to 17 * record size.
                                                              random    random     bkwd    record    stride                                    
              kB  reclen    write  rewrite    read    reread    read     write     read   rewrite      read   fwrite frewrite    fread  freread
              64       4   608965   969761  2561267  2222043  2067979   735831  1363961    763021   1679761   659861   538156  1518251  2278628
              64       8   385790   771797  2278628  2379626  2923952   877797  1562436   1013707   1330167   704914   789967  1879725  2689580
              64      16   390278   821391  3363612  2892445  3541098   866463  1255511   1002351   1279447   877797   955947  1526887  3057153
              64      32   316997   913649  3541098  3165299  3738358   703068  1562436    703068   1828508   863676  1255511  2067979  3363612
              64      64   503814   926260  3057153  4897948  4274062  1033216  1357066    863676   2133730   913649   769584  2067979  3022727
             128       4   506097   870405  1579934  1349580  1421023   586868  1561553   1048974   1802755   826202   805138  2035099  2511022
             128       8   826202  1487977  5325799  4012317  4934216  1440082  2969325   1885042   4135958  1319723  1306873  3657016  2558895
             128      16   406164   940549  3657016  2905056  2511022  1007629  1618028    853794   2035099   836500   814915  1852520  3359523
             128      32   604036  1175271  3867787  3106789  4012317  1105114  2326073   1206978   2905056  1142750  1206978  2286447  4012317
             128      64   604036  1000121  2660335  3759450  4267461  1105114  2377579   1266785   2326073  1196221  1561553  2784517  2969325
             128     128   554157  1142750  3199360  4557257  4407601  1196221  1622919   1048974   2211113  1121270   927549  2098744  2608629
             256       4   567875   937924  2812272  2325094  2392442   897923  2019049   1080434   1881098   886067   858440  2266207  2557711
             256       8   608074  1080434  1956506  2588541  3197509  1089202  2435861   1463250   2719671  1016025   565185  2533571  3123106
             256      16   638445  1157291  2223962  2413957  3159869  1272498  2065659   1561112   3454704  1044693  1123389  2911402  3454704
             256      32   662883  1319408  4132864  3087188  4070199  1224606  2975955   1506359   3654598  1237306  1230218  3465855  4132864
             256      64   672010   977189  2812272  2486631  3245838  1089202  2588541   1422540   3410808  1422540  1391207  2533571  3879045
             256     128   543720  1040643  2639446  3770085  2486631  1274008  2480886   1405778   3087188  1219045  1842366  3511189  4132864
             256     256   654798  1260547  3087188  4132864  4350555  1280084  3245838   1260547   3285566  1254656  1266495  2665657  3756894
             512       4   572691   964378  2860238  2225819  2337255   924123  1467055   1204552   2047551   924123   635951  3299730  3815675
             512       8   930933  1707325  5278892  3068685  3736016  1273861  3239989   1723770   3182373  1132755  1163439  3239989  3481620
             512      16   494264  1279935  3762197  2471765  2975154  1336492  3008498   1190529   2906696  1043072  1672748  5067142  5566231
             512      32  1075998  1854787  3736016  4163357  4271001  2097550  5398323   2486072   3580298  1296159   727268  3437042  3736016
             512      64   565156   997991  2782414  2339802  3556580  1365383  3220553   1712772   6395018  2055390  2132967  5566231  6395018
             512     128   535024  1556366  4163357  3736016  3604335  1527582  3604335   1657257   4061007  1399189  1450212  3284589  4163357
             512     256   724325  1267097  3279573  3481620  3795443  1433753  2304647   1585086   3580298  1462061  2030130  3710197  3481620
             512     512   693675  1312798  3086326  4271001  4163357   997991  2557119   1127995   3366987  1261144  1372364  3163620  3963567
            1024       4   394475   744774  4079544  3366474  3544270  1424152  2090206   1270773   2039583   961529   898941  1602715  2290886
            1024       8   693765  1149061  3696803  2767722  3241960  1122630  1686413   1256277   2774874  1125277  1037480  3345496  3239514
            1024      16   716089  1261072  3655895  1750329  1906496  1193442  4182843   3094790   5444898  2472911   791873  2337008  3506651
            1024      32   734583  1109579  3894582  1973059  2679655   939446  3684119   1824690   3401130  1265904  1323236  3324778  3738636
            1024      64   741559  1287921  3877004  2892612  3894582  1302766  3355952   1865101   3808251  1226150  1356245  3532609  4044965
            1024     128   734583  1358390  4033569  3261656  4321737  1368780  3791442   1800216   2365323  1391395  1361404  3472628  3738636
            1024     256   499484  1324460  3411938  2960401  4064103  1477555  2926114   1542286   2540189  1488307  1402756  3849207  4060261
            1024     512   486472  1406891  3301774  3483896  4162573  1402756  3818408   1488307   2503178  1508167  2081090  2782064  3121783
            1024    1024   533880  1351126  5950309 10454984 10769573  3725664 11520658   3923040   9064828  3984917  3941039 10662628 11018226
            2048       4   512654  1038082  2408974  2021253  2204352  1040598  2260624   1251847   1943069   958291  1417526  3946119  5095447
            2048       8  1756343  2913021  3567536  2335614  2794560  1254040  2820250   1648801   2628655  1117927  1015382  3097921  3384788
            2048      16   721127  1327285  2265991  1843410  2443928  1332432  4196751   4213218   9664580  3276342  3425279  3189957  3189957
            2048      32   759109  1410543  3530875  2767549  3530875  1416357  3470953   1861789   2875960  1140942  1254956  4994712  4653758
            2048      64  1124071  2240576  5785224  4460436  6440169  2144371  4643695   2925920   3922692  1340333  1273562  3413030  3314266
            2048     128   769927  1456709  3210223  2602375  3604966  1603555  4347560   3271351  12345306  3390131  3246623  6807652  3482209
            2048     256   666413  1472440  3671217  2585923  3792790  1362658  2985927   1695335   4356379  1432179  1183870  2993211  3219850
            2048     512   666464  1438174  3175804  2933915  4071433  1492654  3967993   1665101   4014352  1559592  1508115  3806235  4006862
            2048    1024   753515  1341170  2951050  2985927  3723735  1510236  2824887   1688337   6167360  1502575  2149199  2980747  3441748
            2048    2048   740396  1373553  2824887  4172290  4046500  1483118  2909075   1555075   3180508  1492654  1346425  2900235  2572756
            4096       4   613549  1066092  2284616  1918508  2100535   852268  3012001   1939298   2911444  1427159  1408093  3368730  2545993
            4096       8   686788  1234912  2357991  1721118  2445252  1039829  4763181   4188367   5818150  3214912  3245890  3230023  3240992
            4096      16   728028  1325524  4649735  3846119  5278308  2043809  4240052   2673574   4104315  1232963  1101357  2734426  3139133
            4096      32   719852  1416802  3158176  2061467  2900630  1391780  3005151   1343352   4546375  2733991  3110150  8695120  6225028
            4096      64   739084  1494966  3693161  1993300  2700046  1043049  3365430   1978835   3232454  1374410  2002827  3343814  3454069
            4096     128   776182  1199392  3045101  2628979  4003879  1288831  3214912   1422668   2628979  1015610  2612587  6300364  5953231
            4096     256  1487846  2913419  6225028  4847858  6595451  3047261  3767675   1476592   4175134  1368935  1319112  3354915  2678576
            4096     512   739338  1481303  3253266  2838800  4000150  1545674  3000428   1803697   4235870  1446262  1410984  3124859  3349029
            4096    1024   615285  1450413  3485604  3107900  4100397  1479772  2974454   1774815   3973321  1574862  1608781  3052133  3158176
            4096    2048   584134  2047951  3143729  3185110  4023571  1714419  3210107   1411447   3271853  1643722  2121284  2979096  3308398
            4096    4096  1575873  3212508  8377131  3580776  3491981  1038321  3468714   2143249   5910222  3834958  2004931  4112175  4718699
            8192       4   944966  1618009  2412935  2018216  2145632  1455563  6224809   4437634   6638529  3819104  3737270  7635827  2226120
            8192       8   696658  1267708  2874376  3524869  5013966  2460804  6698058   5022027   6838023  3294063  3345053  7669917  7781080
            8192      16   601422  1396521  3037511  2209799  2160336  1455871  7261443   5443725   8342160  3331754  3440857  7930135  6861236
            8192      32   754184  1469947  3172701  3700243  4555903  2812267  8047143   5257958   8532752  3728753  3803041  8127085  3250744
            8192      64   772896  1506490  6131500  6040947  7744251  3768421  6665573   5059743   7468200  3333047  1325361  3564729  2990974
            8192     128   695346  1354088  5748846  5340499  7502444  3742562  3534295   1803584   3100554  1322352  1326640  3127933  3295327
            8192     256   771681  3626431  6877717  5641246  7466577  3693481  8334066   4798976   7461712  3159282  3166561  7019632  7494262
            8192     512  1174820  2002922  3011685  2590683  3334017  1384479  4309076   2815263   6277120  2011834  2021184  4988488  4688953
            8192    1024  1139860  2144025  4531269  3926914  5010310  2294809  4233681   2766527   6325656  2114600  2079659  4667931  3803041
            8192    2048   734326  2769426  5784656  5403489  6633402  2876301  5756551   3363060   8463394  2969263  2768534  5630154  3340825
            8192    4096   580128  2892768  6248582  6715075  7802283  3520535  3123099   1119581   4574098  2408707  2914112  4392252  4081792
            8192    8192   723548  1337016  3171529  3840876  3909933  1951946  3689911   1948183   4081792  1979269  1945756  2586588  2541813
           16384       4   661070  2458586  2460082  1817792  1905814  1508401  1872016   2288299   4886264  2791114  3743950  6919132  7025952
           16384       8  1688364  1196352  2895669  2182484  3466862  2592033  8440323   5337101   7288248  3845133  1145175  5345404  2795428
           16384      16  1114168  1460134  4706553  3175164  4602221  3253484  4211834   2911619   5457909  3190644  4161586  9388155  9367679
           16384      32  2542171  4750476  9735283  8066797  9526105  4588087  8479901   6930296   3255951  1218585  2556831  7080244  7468042
           16384      64  1890816  3694435  7570887  6023371  7680895  3872434  3414835   2610148   5822300  2649087  3865899  3330754  3368303
           16384     128   852886  4342516  9277883  6676457  7706737  4094147  7034583   3081894   5653687  2473809  1235321  2726551  3191385
           16384     256   801834  3966994  7685190  5444935  6858364  3087293  3180749   1954211   3618375  2812245  1256141  4527032  4533603
           16384     512  1146608  3570435  5090027  4244614  5342079  2592424  3146524   1832480   2560070  1471011  2741125  7189127  7126502
           16384    1024   771627  2902886  2774100  2563221  3272230  2458146  8411396   5620854  12672310  3775213  3794390  8525137  8640909
           16384    2048  2221572  3676842  2517952  2512153  2838497  2042620  3180749   2142542   8498779  2683641  3819062  7016626  8333870
           16384    4096  1841910  1383776  4517212  4448494  7007325  3690071  8419641   5364599  10865073  4362087  3570992  3903671  4044509
           16384    8192   791117  3165949  2406919  2429812  2783990  1603280  2778811   1415093   2598895  2122818  6253589  7888086  7961193
           16384   16384  2322325  1351367  3193758  4177525  5204914  3259967  2705831   1991014   3625438  1956994  2581322  5092668  4972535
           32768      64  1130591  1950933  3347450  2948650  5701960  3720720 10641968   9285282  11377579  5111191  1294251  3398773  3896346
           32768     128  1454029  5851253  3247243  2818520  4632283  2411175  9860874   7171798   9917800  4321734  1523953 10934055 10368990
           32768     256  1060380  3831605 11457250 10256021 12226788  6791198  4614553   3651522   8346424  4219438  2457127  5890374  5947213
           32768     512  1479097  1695880  9168828  7785230  9222973  4772549  3124336   2226856   8480323  2600409  1669958  9863705  9537215
           32768    1024  1111454  1612039  6788514  6929180  8623455  4579648  4554909   3321642   7148670  3719411  5211191 11386062  3075673
           32768    2048  1749971  5705748  3067299  2686358  4458278  3541346  3041370   2150144   8161067  3170024  1531919  9583767  9957320
           32768    4096  2396377  1600233  3091864  2987621  6073896  3672304  5784271   3642426  10778844  4229306  2275260 10824687 11275834
           32768    8192  2809532  1598670  7363535  5817077  8088543  4114469  2800715   3452216   8257663  4517183  1698794  7947293  7956955
           32768   16384  2398844  1971360  6311254  6297950  6938275  4667205  2760383   1887902   6063713  3797935  6526126  2624593  3914546
           65536      64  2090265  2187441  7700134  6197251  7989288  5288981 11686088   7098055   9659139  4206704  1793588  3389503  5665739
           65536     128  3079560  2079906  3239696  3914925  7992308  5309105  3134769   5252095  11023421  5696384  2724752 11487802 11235187
           65536     256  2906644  1574854  3308202  5732737  9121306  5709636  4695572   5251292  10443766  5458604  1864668  5960083  5844635
           65536     512  1934536  2150208  3094955  4492804  8492324  5267797  5968625   5496150  10819917  2978227  5979531  3151228  4377817
           65536    1024  2122071  6665677 11387858 10017852 12172538  6367659  3030299   6534629  11991983  5688368  1757331 11626281 11115696
           65536    2048  3334812  2187233  3441100  6164729  9752352  5796567  3000332   6467592  12321498  4680142  1915301  6063687  5961634
           65536    4096  1849214  5914302 11008852  9972060 12258854  5754339  3634037   4743870  14611989  4247855  2777672 11156752 11503667
           65536    8192  3001840  2811365  2922311  5826918  8420522  5214929  3244667   4968618   9135250  2528966  4855658  9617906  9610844
           65536   16384  3174263  5402813  8199239  7989288  9176420  5082349  9145280   4841291   8712507  5375343  2765710  3200653  5786317
          131072      64  3627582  2605690  4186931  7997052 11523876  6546753  4989035   9415431  12011845  5968418  3246292  4150484 10152685
          131072     128  3725117  2822636  4692038  8139127 12088176  6641664  3862331   9362995  11955682  2409151  2676033  3932675  9770517
          131072     256  3701565  2575501  3832418  7964958 11710185  6668976  3298829   8668792   6747555  5347257  2850930  3738823  9214844
          131072     512  3740858  5834512  4434558  8364001 12236971  6659847  3626170   8885113   6956397  5383966  2644763  5037170 10569421
          131072    1024  3720554  5989094  8783752  7539804 11872543  6653399  3754141   7973275  11998475  5935169  2557648  4054940  9333745
          131072    2048  3697582  2582446 12259894 10193725 12739156  6451336  4220909   8555071  12958357  5086996  3950564  4274735  9966782
          131072    4096  3372325  2748190  6528483  8572948 12623901  5680011  6427576   6950856   7588197  4013231  2584886  4027284  9547719
          131072    8192  3239463  2714658  3647486  7779658  9020848  5556523  4003441   5706246   9517305  4456414  3571749  4030887  6180030
          131072   16384  2457846  2527859  4399848  7621439  8926809  5241020  3952694   5693835   8851923  4724172  2667800  3981521  8097886
          262144      64  2407130  4097918 11861759  5989806 12240623  6446109  4966921  11000527  12864629  5941192  5548022 13330515 12909034
          262144     128  3763468  6018659  7902321 10014696 12236672  6612776  7846715  10880457  12722323  5983091  3184573  5952675 12050392
          262144     256  3738820  4557753  5696307 10089502 12190004  6743450  5120991   9972731  12266296  5845300  4182930  6522589  8536328
          262144     512  3679058  4368640  6166057 10160548 12170035  6760450  6304401   9847242  12491922  5903329  3473851  5474897 12058586
          262144    1024  3753063  4063418  7461256 10166091 12432737  6674393  5675724   9847330  12865833  5813160  3670252  6665411 12343272
          262144    2048  2853237  5984589  5361488  7022725 12713791  6506262  5889542   9381033   8345895  4936726  3377969  5214618 12287544
          262144    4096  3391829  5745511 10001669  9917678 12083102  5760622 10685368   7381660   8495173  3566197  2977150  5632432 12653509
          262144    8192  3260045  4099705  6130132  8279217  9737877  5428753  5026343   5956577   9654764  4350438  4348408  5189317  7346101
          262144   16384  3225955  3421626  5230220  6810364  8907125  5317203  5027607   5662716   7386817  4448387  3138925  9027277  9259762
          524288      64  3695652  5180513  7256668 10565633 12333843  6459834  7870412  10598733  10643930  6084064  4440867  8817473 12971001
          524288     128  3022530  6275289  8277248 10649342 12441868  6656368  7840051  10851881  12612491  5975463  4457249  7361220 10281151
          524288     256  3741631  4991690  6991439  8557449 12110505  6666761 12255755   9900434  12333290  5872207  4187205  7420388 12377858
          524288     512  3755240  6244212  7679392 10038827 12343466  6694525  8023998   9957188  10177185  5906005  4388998  7749320 12404811
          524288    1024  2990567  5151846  7961855 10436115 12571680  6753429  7873484  10008534  12741475  5834426  4549407 10990620 12732843
          524288    2048  3711038  5778800  7342245 10503158 12688175  6546820  7620684   9980326  12888138  5076959  3917098  7412734 12453988
          524288    4096  3393230  4651902  7531680 10380301 12466414  5833126  7811672   7884267  10888420  3794783  3396328  7764122 10280142
          524288    8192  2643286  4080033  7058653  8411074  9685372  5393691  6831645   5843402   8576172  3970195  3609626  6492639  8312133
          524288   16384  3076538  4731679  6996177  7957390  9027307  5270393  7794836   5642908   8827171  4345708  3788703  6670158  9066648
```